# Status bar hides but views are displaced in Landscape mode

Tags: ios

In my app, I do not intend to show the status bar. So, my app covers the whole screen view. I could manage doing it inserting the

```
- (BOOL) prefersStatusBarHidden{
    return YES;
}
```

method in my main viewController and also adding to my app delegate

```
 if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]) {
       // iOS 7
       [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
 } else {
       // iOS 6
       [application setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
 }
```

This all works well when I open the app in the portrait mode. However, when opened in the landscape mode, while the status bar gets hidden, I see a black band of background image on top of my view. Indeed my view is vertically offset by the height of status bar height (see picture below).

This does not happen if I open the app first in portrait mode and then rotate. So, I am doing something wrong in the initialization of the view frame I thought, which I do by the usual

```
   CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];    
   [self.view setFrame:screenRect];
```

Any suggestions on this would be really appreciated. 
Thanks in advance,
Nikhil

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed the issue (at least for now). I did not fix in the `info-plist` the options

[image]

I hate this. To do one single setting one has to add so many things, that too in different places: one in the appDelegate, other in the main view controller and yet another completely outside the code :(.